# UDP socket server, 3 listening sockets at time [Python]

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I would like to write a UDP server in Python, which would have 3 different sockets listening on different ports at time. The main job of the server is to send clients a constant text, different for different socket.

I wrote the below code:

```
import socket
import thread

def create_socket_server(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((host, port))
    return s


def run_socket(s, secret):
    while True:
        (data, addr) = s.recvfrom(1024)
        s.sendto(secret, addr)


def run_server():
    s1 = create_socket_server('127.0.0.1', 2000)
    s2 = create_socket_server('127.0.0.1', 3000)
    s3 = create_socket_server('127.0.0.1', 4000)

    while 1:
        thread.start_new_thread(run_socket, (s1, "A"))
        thread.start_new_thread(run_socket, (s2, "B"))
        thread.start_new_thread(run_socket, (s3, "C"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

But after I ran it it showed that:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/brian/Temp/udp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brian/Temp/udp.py", line 29, in <module>
    run_server()
  File "/home/brian/Temp/udp.py", line 24, in run_server
    thread.start_new_thread(run_socket, (s2, "SI"))
thread.error: can't start new thread

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are continually trying to re-start the sockets, as they fall under the never ending "while" loop. Remove the "while 1" and instead make your loop at the bottom of the script. could even be

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
```

This way it will start your threads and then move on, in this case into a never ending sleep. Just as an example. Hope it helps.